# Discarded non-Unit value Error When Using Akka

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I have Scala Play application and I am invoking the Scala Akka Scheduler in the class like this:

```scala
@Singleton
class Foo @Inject() (
  actorSystem: ActorSystem,
)(implicit
  executionContext: ExecutionContext,
 ) extends Logging {

  actorSystem.scheduler.schedule(delay, interval)(poller())

  def poller(): Unit ...
}
```

But I get a compiler warning like this

```scala
discarded non-Unit value
[error]   actorSystem.scheduler.schedule(delay, interval)(poller())
```

Is there a way to suppress this or code this in some way to eliminate the compiler error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the [`Scheduler.schedule`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/actor/Scheduler.html#schedule(initialDelay:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,interval:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration)(f:=>Unit)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):akka.actor.Cancellable) method returns a [`Cancellable`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/actor/Cancellable.html) instance to allow the job to be cancelled, but this code ignores the return value. When the compiler flag `-Ywarn-value-discard` or `-Wvalue-discard` is set, this issues a warning. If the compiler also has `-Xfatal-warnings` or `-Werror` set, these warnings become errors.

One workaround is to explicitly ignore the return value, rather than implicitly:

```
val _ = actorSystem.scheduler.schedule(delay, interval)(poller())
```